# Unable to pass radio button selection value to controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My if/else conditions in controller is not getting Called :

My View Page :

```
 <%= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do %>

   <%=  radio_button_tag :name,  :time, true %> 
      <strong>Send Password Reset Link to Mail </strong>
   <%=  radio_button_tag :name, :graph %>
      <strong> Get Recovery Code on Mobile </strong>

<%= submit_tag %>
```

in controller :

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
         if params[:name] == :time
            user.send_password_reset 

        elsif params[:name] == :graph
           user.send_password_mobile
        end

    redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Instructions sent!'
end
```

Comment: look at the console where server is running to see what is the value of `params[:name]`, I suspect it is a `String` like `"time"` and not a symbol

Comment: I think the params value is coming different than your condition so  put `raise params.inspect` at the beginning of create method and check the params value.

Comment: tihom: Yes you are correct, it's treated as string hence I am able to verify it by comparing "time" & "graph" in my Create action. 

Amit: Thanks for your valuable note, this has helped me !